# Autenticação Django com Base de Dados Legado

Tags: python, django, firebird

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com um banco de dados legado (Firebird), e consegui fazer a configuração do settings.py e está funcionando com o banco de dados.

Na hora de criar um login usando forms, não estou conseguindo criar uma autenticação com o banco, pois não estou usando a tabela padrão de usuário do django, e estou tentando validar com uma tabela já existente do sistema legado.

Alguem poderia me orientar de como seria feito a criação de um login utilizando uma tabela já existente do sistema legado? E principalmente a parte da views.py para autenticar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa criar um authentication backend customizado, veja https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Você pode copiar e colar o modelo do django, e especificar no seu modelo o nome da tabela e de cada coluna

Na verdade pode não ser tão simples assim, eu não sei como as senhas são armazenadas no sistema legado, na verdade você nem precisa criar uma tabela, você pode criar a sua própria logica de autenticação, como por exemplo autenticar em um sistema remoto como AD/LDAP